# Azure AD and Subscribed SKUs Audit

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to "track" the changes to a tenant's subscribed SKUs on a daily basis?

I can only think of two ways using the Graph API:

1. Query the [subscribedSkus](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_list) endpoint each day and log the consumedUnits attribute
2. Take a baseline reading of consumedUnits and then query the [directoryAudits](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/directoryaudit_list) endpoint to track audits of licences being added / removed?

We have a particularly difficult customer who manages their own product licences and neglect to tell us when they have revoked/granted any licences; when they get their invoice, they then kick up a storm because they're getting billed for days licences weren't assigned.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for daily numbers, it's probably simplest to just query daily and keep track of the previous day's value.

If you're looking for near real-time notifications, then you could also use [change notifications](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks) (webhooks) or [delta query](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview) (or better, a combination of both), to detect license assignments.

Comment: Ah yes, webhooks!  This is probably going to be the way I go I think; not for the "real-time" notifications but because they do alter licence assignments so frequently and the way licences work on CSP means we need to know if a licence if assigned and revoked immediately (for example), thanks for the tip

Comment: Then I suggest looking at change notifications (webhooks) to "signal" your service to pull changes with a delta query. (Make sure to set a minimum amount of wait time between delta query polls, in case you have a particularly busy tenant, so that you don't get throttled. The webhook is more to avoid unnecessary polling if there aren't any changes. The delta query is what will actually give you the details.)